# Couldn't present bibliography and citations numbered in Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, overleaf

Unfortunately my thesis on Overleaf does not present the bibliography and citations by numbers for each source. I use the `natbib` package. I know there is another package, `bibtex` for bibliography, but it didn't compile with the `utf8x` package, which I must use in order to compile my thesis.

The code I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{square,numbers ,comma ,sort&compress, super} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{datetime}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
    % Useful packages
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}


 \begin{document}

 Some text. \cite{ADSCFT,Bethe} Another citation. \cite{BM}


\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{../sample.bib}

\end{document}
```

The file `sample.bib` is given by:

```
    @article{ADSCFT,
    doi = {10.1007/s11005-011-0516-7},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1007%2Fs11005-011-0516-7},
    year = 2011,
    month = {aug},
    publisher = {Springer Science and Business Media {LLC}
},
    volume = {99},
    number = {1-3},
    pages = {425--453},
    author = {Gregory P. Korchemsky},
    title = {Review of {AdS}/{CFT} Integrability, Chapter {IV}.4: Integrability in {QCD} and {\textdollar}{\textdollar}$\lbrace${\textbackslash}fancyscript$\lbrace$N$\rbrace$ {\&}lt$\mathsemicolon$4 $\rbrace${\textdollar}{\textdollar} {SYM}},
    journal = {Letters in Mathematical Physics}
}

@article{Bethe,
  title={Zur Theorie der Metalle},
  author={Hans A. Bethe},
  journal={Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Physik},
  year={1931},
  volume={71},
  pages={205-226}
}

@book{BM,
    author    = "Bill Sutherland",
    title     = "Beautiful Models: 70 Years of Exactly Solved Quantum Many-Body Problems",
    year      = "2004",
    publisher = "World Scientific",
 }
```

But the output for the Bibliography is given by:
[image]

As we can see that the sources are not numbered although I added `numbers` in the `natbib` usepackage section.

EDIT:

I don`t know why, but when I changed the order of the package insertions   my file was compiled numbered in Overleaf.
instead of the above Insertion I wrote:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst,square,numbers,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{datetime}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{braket}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
 \usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}   
   \usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you removed the input commands (`\input{titlepage_heb}`), as we do not have these files and they only produce errors. It would also be helpful if you provided the code for your `.bib` file.

Comment: Unrelated: you should not be using `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`, if you need the `inputenc` package use the `utf8` option, it is actively maintained.

Comment: As others have mentioned please make sure others can compile your example, we don't have all those files you `\input`.

Comment: now I edited my code so everyone could compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you need the `natbib` package. Anyway, using `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` works fine for me. Here is a minimal example (mind the path for the `.bib` file):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum} %generate text

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction} \label{intro}
    \lipsum[1-1] \cite{argall2011teacher}
    \lipsum[1-1] \cite{li2018oil}
    
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{../biblio.bib}
\end{document}
```

Btw, when posting questions, try to make minimal examples which would compile without requiring specific files ;)

Comment: unfortunately, deleting the \uspackage[natbib] didn`t help to  produce numbered sources in the bibliography for me...

Comment: The idea is to use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` ... not to delete `natbib`

Comment: Still even when including 'natbib'  The numbers not appear

Comment: weird... can you share an working example (preferably simplified)?

Comment: I edited my code in the main question, is now simplified such that everyone can compile

Comment: comment the natbib and the respective style options

`%\usepackage{natbib}`
`%\setcitestyle{square,numbers ,comma ,sort&compress, super} `

Use the `unsrt` bibliography style
`\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`

Be sure you have the `.bib` file in the same folder you indicate in the `\bibliography` command.
`\bibliography{sample.bib}`

It works on a blank overleaf project. Unless you **must** have natbib for some obscure reason.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[image]

You put the `square,numbers, comma ,sort&compress, super` in a square braket when loading `natbib`: `\usepackage[square,numbers, comma ,sort&compress, super]{natbib}`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[square,numbers, comma ,sort&compress, super]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}


\begin{document}

some text. \cite{einstein}. Another citation. \cite{latexcompanion,einstein}
Final citation \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}

\medskip

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

And here is the `sample.bib` file:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

> I know there is another package bibtex for bibliography

Did you know that there is a third option called `biblatex`? I use this one since this has more citation styles than `natbib`. However, I do not know if it will work with `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`.

Comment: unfortunately, this change didn`t produce numbered sources in the bibliography for me...

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the `biblatex` library instead. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

%\usepackage[square,numbers, comma ,sort&compress, super]{natbib}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{datetime}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
    % Useful packages
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

some text. \cite{einstein}. Another citation. \supercite{latexcompanion,einstein}
Final citation \supercite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}

\printbibliography
%\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

What you need to change:

- add `\usepackage[style=chem-angew]{biblatex}` right after this add
- `\addbibresource{references.bib}` instead of
- `\bibliography{references.bib}` write `\printbibliography` instead of
- `\cite` use `\supercite`

Comment: I know that biblatex is very comfortable, unfortunately it did not compile well when introduced to  \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}, I have to use utf8x instead of utf8 in order to present two pages out of the thesis in Hebrew, utf8 is not compiling Hebrew only gibberish...